# Python 2 Merge Data Frames into one Table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with this loop:

```
for elem in dfList:
   flatlist=[]
   for item in elem:
      flatlist.append(item)
      df = pd.DataFrame([flatlist], columns = ['Target', 'Position', 'Residue', 'Kinase'])
      print(type(df))
```

And retrieving:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

How can I merge all the frames into one single table without using the package dplyr. I'm with Python 2.7.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `dfList` is it actually a list of DataFrames? You can just `pd.concat` them.

Comment: ```dfList``` It's a list of lists, so I can't ```pd.concat```.